# postRestart and preRestart methods are not getting invoke in akka actots

Tags: scala, akka, actor, lifecycle, akka-supervision

I am following [this tutorial](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/understand-methods-akka-actors-scala-lifecycle) here is my code

```
case class ArtGroupDeleteFromES (uuidList:List[String]) 
class ArtGroupDeleteESActor extends Actor{
val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass)
    override def preStart() {
      log.debug("preStart  Starting ArtGroupDeleteESActor instance hashcode # {}",
       this.hashCode())
      }

    override def postStop() {
      log.debug("postStop Stopping ArtGroupDeleteESActor instance hashcode # {}",
       this.hashCode())
      }

    override def preRestart(reason: Throwable, message: Option[Any]) {
      log.debug("I am restarting")
      log.debug("ArtGroupDeleteESActor: preRestart")
      log.debug(s" MESSAGE: ${message.getOrElse("")}")
      log.debug(s" REASON: ${reason.getMessage}")
      super.preRestart(reason, message)
      }

    override def postRestart(reason: Throwable) {
      log.debug("restart completed!")
      log.debug("ArtGroupDeleteESActor: postRestart")
      log.debug(s" REASON: ${reason.getMessage}")
      super.postRestart(reason)
      }
def receive = {
  case ArtGroupDeleteFromES(uuidList) =>
 throw new Exception("Booom")
  sender ! true
   }
  case  message => 
    log.warn("Received unknown message: {}", message)
    unhandled(message)
 }

}
```

and here is the how i am sending this actor a message

```
class ArtGroupDeletionActor extends Actor{

  val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass)
 override val supervisorStrategy = OneForOneStrategy(
                                    maxNrOfRetries = 10, withinTimeRange = 10 seconds) {
    case _:Exception => Restart
  }
 val artGroupDeleteESActor=context.actorOf(Props[ArtGroupDeleteESActor]
      .withDispatcher("akka.actor.ArtGroupDeleteESActor-dispatcher")
      ,name = "ArtGroupDeleteESActor")

   def receive = {

    case DeleteArtGroup(uuidList) =>
      val future1  = ask(artGroupDeleteESActor, ArtGroupDeleteFromES(uuidList)).mapTo[Boolean]
      var isDeletedfromES = Await.result(future1, timeout.duration)
    case message =>
      log.warn("Unhandled message received : {}", message)
      unhandled(message)
  }
}

object test extends App{
 val artGroupDeletionActor=system.actorOf(Props[ArtGroupDeletionActor]
      .withDispatcher("akka.actor.ArtGroupDeletionActor-dispatcher")
      ,name = "ArtGroupDeletionActor")
     artGroupDeletionActor ! DeleteArtGroup(List("123"))
}
```

the PostRestart() and preRestart()  methods are not invoking,but preStart() and postStop() gets called, please guide me where i am doing wrong

Comment: Where do you send `ForceRestart`? This is the message that triggers the restart in an actor.

Comment: here  val future1  = ask(artGroupDeleteESActor, ArtGroupDeleteFromES(uuidList)).mapTo[Boolean]

Comment: in my code its ArtGroupDeleteFromES(uuidList) instead of ForceRestart but the working is same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(for simplicity I'll call your actors `Parent` and `Child` from now on)

What happens here is that when an exception occurs inside `Child.receive`, it doesn't send a response to `Parent`, instead, the actor system sends some control instruction for the supervision strategy. However, `Parent` is blocked on `Await` waiting for completion of `future1`, which only happens after the `timeout` exceeds, and then, in turn, a `TimeoutException` is thrown inside `Parent.receive`, killing (restarting) the `Parent` actor itself, and thus the supervising message of an exception in `Child` is then passed to `deadLetters`, never restarting the `Child`.

You should never, ever, **ever** block inside an actor, so this is incorrect:

```
  val future1 = ask(artGroupDeleteESActor, ArtGroupDeleteFromES(uuidList)).mapTo[Boolean]
  var isDeletedfromES = Await.result(future1, timeout.duration)
```

Instead, you have to either utilize some kind of message identification to distinguish one reply from another in concurrent environment, or add an `onComplete` to the Future and send a message to `self` in the closure (beware: *no logic other than sending a message should be executed inside the closure to the Future!*).

So, option A:

```
case class ArtGroupDeleteFromES(id: Long, uuidList: List[String])
case class ArtGroupDeleteFromESResult(id: Long, success: Boolean)

class Parent extends Actor {
  override val supervisionStrategy = ...
  var msgId = 0L
  var pendingRequesters = Map.empty[Long, ActorRef]
  val child = context.actorOf(Props[Child])

  def nextId = {
    msgId += 1
    msgId
  }

  def receive = {
    case DeleteArtGroup(uuidList) =>
      val id = nextId
      pendingRequesters += id -> sender() // store a reference to the sender so that you can send it a message when everything completes
      child ! DeleteArtGroupFromES(nextId, uuidList)
    case ArtGroupDeleteFromESResult(id, success) =>
      // process result...
      pendingRequesters(id) ! "done"
      pendingRequesters -= id
  }
}
```

And option B:

```
case class ArtGroupDeleteFromES(uuidList: List[String])
case class ArtGroupDeleteFromESResult(replyTo: ActorRef, success: Boolean)

class Parent extends Actor {
  override val supervisionStrategy = ...
  val child = context.actorOf(Props[Child])

  def receive = {
    case DeleteArtGroup(uuidList) =>
      val requester = sender() // when the future completes, sender may have already changed, so you need to remember it
      (child ? DeleteArtGroupFromES(uuidList)).onComplete {
        case Success(success) => self ! ArtGroupDeleteFromESResult(requester, success)
        case Failure(e) =>
          log.warn("Could not delete...", e) 
          self ! ArtGroupDeleteFromESResult(requester, success = false)
  }
}
```